# How to prompt the user to only enter one of three options they can choose from and display an error message for wrong input

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

This program will prompt the user to enter a medium (either air, water or steel) and the distance. Then calculate the distance a sound wave will travel through the medium.

I wrote the whole program but I didn't read the last bit that my professor added to the homework which is the following paragraph. Now I'm stuck because I'm not quite sure how to add this to my program. I was using an if statements but maybe I can add it in one?

The program prompts for the medium with: "Enter one of the following: air, water, or steel:" and reads the medium. If the medium is not air, water, or steel the program prints the message: "Sorry, you must enter air, water, or steel" and nothing else. Otherwise the program prompts for the following distance input.

I tried a `while` loop and adding another `if` statement but really my problem is the syntax. Because I've never had to command the user to type in specific strings.

```
public class SpeedOfSound {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double distance;
        double time;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        //prompt the user to enter the medium through which sound will 
        System.out.print("Enter one of the following: air, water, or steel:");
        String input;
        input = keyboard.nextLine();

        // prompt the user to enter a distance

        System.out.print("Enter distance in feet: ");

        distance = keyboard.nextDouble();

        // determine if medium is air, water, steele and calculate

        if (input.equals("air")) {
            time = (distance / 1100);
            System.out.println("The total time traveled is " + time + " feet per second.");
        }
        else if (input.equals("water"))

        {
            time = (distance / 4900);
            System.out.println("The total time traveled is " + time + " feet per second.");
        }

        else if (input.equals("steel"))
        {
            time = (distance / 16400);
            System.out.println("The total time traveled is " + time + " feet per second.");
        }
    }
}
```

My expected result is to make the user only type in either Air, water, or Steel.

Comment: In order to repeat asking the user for input after a wrong choice, you will need a while loop.

Comment: You're on the right track with a while loop. You'll want to store the users input and check it against perhaps a HashSet -`mySet.contains(userInput)` - every iteration through the while loop to see if it's an acceptable input

Answer (score 1):

There was several issue with your code and I've taken the liberty of correcting them. Read through the comments to better understand each part of the code.

```
public class SpeedOfSound
{
    /* Best to declare it here so other methods have access to it. */
    private static final Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    /*
     * Declared as a class field so you can use it if you
     * have a need for it in addition to time calculated in main.
     */
    private static double distance;

    /**
     * Blocks program execution until a number has been detected as user input.
     * @return numeric representation of user input.
     */
    public static double getDistance()
    {
        System.out.println("Enter distance in feet: ");
        // CAREFUL: This will throw an exception if the user enters a String
        // return keyboard.nextDouble();
        while (keyboard.hasNext())
        {
            /*
             * Check if the user input is actually a number
             * and if it isn't print an error and get next token
             */
            String input = keyboard.nextLine();
            try {
                return Double.valueOf(input);
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("Incorrect input, try again.");
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("Scanner doesn't have any more tokens.");
    }

    /**
     * Calculate the speed of sound for user input which is limited to:
     * <ul>
     *     <li>Air</li>
     *     <li>Water</li>
     *     <li>Steel</li>
     * </ul>
     * @return total time traveled in feet per second.
     */
    public static Double calculate()
    {
        Double time = null;

        //prompt the user to enter the medium through which sound will travel through
        System.out.println("Enter one of the following: air, water, or  steel:");

        // The loop will break the moment time is calculated
        while (time == null && keyboard.hasNext())
        {
            double distance;
            String input = keyboard.nextLine();

            //determine if medium is air, water, steele and calculate

            if (input.equals("air"))
            {
                distance = getDistance();
                time = (distance / 1100);
            }
            else if (input.equals("water"))
            {
                distance = getDistance();
                time = (distance / 4900);
            }
            else if (input.equals("steel"))
            {
                distance = getDistance();
                time = (distance / 16400);
            }
            else System.out.println("Incorrect input, try again.");
        }
        return time;
    }

    public static void main(String[ ] args)
    {
        Double time = calculate();
        System.out.println("The total time traveled is " + time + " feet per second.");
    }
}
```

However the way I would tackle this assignment would be to implement the elements in an `enum` of sort and move the bulk of the `calculate()` method there. This will allow you to quickly create more elements like `air`, `water` and `steel` without having to create additional `if` blocks to process them.

**Element Enumerator**

```
public enum Element {

    AIR("air", 1100),
    WATER("water", 4900),
    STEEL("steel", 16400);

    private final String name;
    private final int factor;

    Element(String name, int factor) {
        this.name = name;
        this.factor = factor;
    }

    /**
     * @param element name of the element to calculate time for
     * @return total time traveled in feet per second for given element or
     *         {@code null} if no element matched the given name.
     */
    public static Double getTimeTraveledFor(String element)
    {
        /* Find an element that matches the given name */
        for (Element e : Element.values()) {
            /*
             * Validate the parameter without case consideration.
             * This might be a better way of validating input unless
             * for some reason you really want a case-sensitive input
             */
            if (e.name.equalsIgnoreCase(element)) {
                return SpeedOfSound.getDistance() / e.factor;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Revised method**

```
public static Double calculate()
{
    Double time = null;

    //prompt the user to enter the medium through which sound will travel through
    System.out.println("Enter one of the following: air, water, or  steel:");

    // The loop will break the moment time is calculated
    while (time == null && keyboard.hasNext())
    {
        String input = keyboard.nextLine();
        time = Element.getTimeTraveledFor(input);
        if (time == null) {
            System.out.printf("%s is not a recognized element, try again.", input);
        }
    }
    return time;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    while(true){  
     System.out.print("Enter distance in feet: ");

    String input;
                input = keyboard.nextLine();


     //prompt the user to enter a distance


     System.out.print("Enter distance in feet: ");

     distance = keyboard.nextDouble();

     //determine if medium is air, water, steele and calculate

        if (input.equals("air"))
        {


        time = (distance / 1100);

        System.out.println("The total time traveled is " + time + " 
     feet per second.");
    break;
        }

        else if (input.equals("water"))

        {
        time = (distance / 4900);

        System.out.println("The total time traveled is " + time + " 
     feet per second.");
    break;

         }



         else if (input.equals("steel"))

         {

          time = (distance / 16400);

          System.out.println("The total time traveled is " + time + " 
     feet per second.");
    break;


          }
else
 System.out.println("wrong choice");

}
```

Comment: Please consider adding a comment if you think this answer can be improved.

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter; but I think this answer could be improved by including at least a brief description of what the problem with the original code was, what you have changed and (if necessary) how that alleviates the problem.

Comment: ok thanks but it is  just a while loop with break statement it is simple solution

Comment: I'm not the downvoter - but if the user enters the wrong choice of medium, there is no point in asking for distance and time before giving an error message.

Comment: can you explain

Comment: The user should only be prompted to enter the distance if the medium was a correct option.

Comment: @MohammadSommakia The solution is a bit more complex as it requires additional validation. Implementing a loop to keep asking for input is just part of the solution.